# Record call for speaker (one side) only

Tags: android, voice-recording

I use:

```
MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)
```

or

```
AudioRecord.Builder.setAudioSource(int)
```

record both [voice in call](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource#VOICE_CALL).

I need to know that record call for caller only, mean could't record my voice in the call (voice from mic) possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording only caller's voice could not well supported on all devices/implementations.
Moreover this behaviour could change from one Android version to another according to what Manufacturers want to open their devices.
Many devices can record only BOTH streams, others can record only from MIC...
Starting from Android 7.1 Nougat up to 8.1 it is not possibile to record Voicecalls if the App is not signed using the System Certificate, so only System App developed by the Vendor could record voicecalls.
Few bugs were discovered in these years to let the developer records even if the System denies it, but those remains quite secrets to few developers.

However to record only called voice you have to set the Source as "AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK".

Comment: I tried what you told me to do in 8.1 but the phone couldn't the format of the voice file when the voice source set as (down_link) but it reads it when voice source set as (comunication) or (mic)   Do you have any idea about this

Comment: I wrote that "starting from 7.1 is not possibile to record voicecalls if the app is not signed using the System Certificate". Some manifacturer could has create an alternative way but it's completly manufacturer dependant. You can try by setting VOICE_DOWNLINK but I think it will not work in most of devices when running 7.1+.

Comment: i tried versions less than 7 and also not working  so is there any way to do that ?

Comment: I say again: it depends on Manufacturer and on what Android version you're using. It's very variable. Before Android 7.0 this can be achieved by using Reflection (there are many posts on StackOverflow about that), but after Android 7.1 the things starts to begin very difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but i have one more question . can i Record call for specific time (record 10 sec from the call for example) during the call?

Comment: If you achieve "Recoriing a call" then you can record at any time and for how much long you want.